# How to pass copied text to other activity in Android

Tags: android, webview, clipboard, android-activity, android-preferences

I'm developing a Dictionary app to run on Android 3+

In **Activity1**, there is an EditText box in which user enters words s/he wants to look up. The meanings of the words are then displayed in **Activity2** using Webview.

I know in Android 3+, user can long-press an item on web view and copy it to clipboard. Hence, I'm thinking of adding a button in Activity2 to deal with any text copied to clipboard. To clarify, I want when this button is clicked, Activity1 will be called and the copied text will be automatically pasted into its EditText box (for looking up)

**How could I programmatically do this?**

I will be very grateful if you can provide an example and/or tutorial. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, guys. But sorry for my ignorance, no-one mentions how to pass the word copied in Activity2, currently in the clipboard and has to be sent to EditText of Activity1. Any ideas?

Comment: The word that you copy onto your clipboard, it'll be stored in a `String`,right? You don't need to access the clipboard content as long as you have that specific `String` at your disposal.

Answer (score 1):

pass your value from activity1 to activity2 using intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("MyValue", value);
startActivityForResult(i, ActDocument.DIALOG_DOCUMENTDETAIL);
```

In Activity2

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    value = intent.getSerializableExtra("MyValue");
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preferences to store Strings or other values. 
in another activity in button click event use shared preferences to get string and then set it into the Edit text..

Answer (score 0):

In Activity 1:

```
SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
prefsEditor.putString("word1", string1);
//so on for other 'n' number of words you have
prefsEditor.commit();
```

In Activity 2:

```
SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
String meaning1 = appSharedPrefs.getString("word1", "meaning not found");
//so on for other 'n' number of words
```

Answer (score 0):

in  Activity 2:On button click:

```
Intent it = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity1.class);
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("word", "Android");
it.putExtras(bundle);   
startActivity(it);
```

in Activity 1:

```
Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle !=null)
{
String name=bundle.getString("word");
EditText edttxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtboxtest);
edttxt.setText(name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But Eclipse throws this error: `05-12 15:09:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1437): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{niamh.nadict/niamh.nadict.Nadict}: java.lang.NullPointerException`. I guess it has problems calling Activity1. I put the stuff for Activity1 in OnCreate. Is it right?